# What word class/part of speech is " the doctor's " in " the doctor's office "?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, possessives, determiners

I need to be able to identify the word classes/parts of speech of each word in a sentence such as:
"He walked into the doctor's office."
Is it a possessive determiner? A possessive adjective? A possessive noun?

This wikipedia page indicates (without reference) that it can be called a determiner: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_determiner. I see the parallel with "The doctor called him; he walked into her office," where "her" - which is a possessive determiner - serves an almost identical function as "the doctor's". It's determining the specificity of the office, much like the determiners "**the** office" or (**that** office). However, most pages I've found on determiners don't mention this type of formation, and they present determiners as a closed word class (which logically can't include all cases of "[noun]'s").

"Doctor" in the sense referred to here is a noun, and the 's commonly shows possession, but in the case of "the doctor's office" the word "doctor's" isn't a noun in its own right, is it? Without the head noun "office", it doesn't signify any specific object, merely the quality of belonging (as in "the doctor's house", "the doctor's garden" etc).

As it's modifying/adding information about the office, is it an adjective in this case?

Does it depend on whether "the" is considered to be referring to the (specific) doctor or to the (specific) office?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In "He walked into the doctor's office", "the doctor's" is a genitive **noun** phrase (note the 's genitive marking). Its function in the clause is **'determiner'**. Many people say 'possessive' instead of genitive, though the latter is the correct term.

Comment: Both terms are fine; neither is incorrect, and in English they refer to the same phenomena. _Genitive_ has a checkered past as a case name, but English no longer has cases, so _possessive_ carries fewer Latinate presuppositions. _The doctor_ is clearly a noun phrase, and the clitic _-'s_ marks it as a possessive.

Comment: 'Possessive' would hardly be appropriate for something like "her rapid action" and "her acceptance of the offer". Neither of those permits a natural paraphrase with possess in the way that _her car_ can be paraphrased as _the car she possesses_. Case most certainly does still exist, though it is limited to pronouns which have nominative and accusative contrast, in addition to genitive.

Comment: Thanks Bill and John! To check whether I understand correctly: in this phrase, "the doctor's"  is both a noun phrase and a determiner? The word class is 'Noun Phrase' and the function is 'Determiner'?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. _Doctor's_ is a noun, and _the doctor's_ is a noun phrase, the equivalent phrasal category.

Comment: Thanks Bill. If I may be permitted to further shine a torch around my cavern of ignorance: If,as you say, the words "the doctor's" in the phrase "the doctor's office" is a noun, does that mean that the word "her" in the phrase "her office" is a pronoun, as well as being a determiner? If so, can words belong to multiple word classes  simultaneously (within the same context)? Or is 'determiner' not a word class in the way that 'noun', 'adverb', 'conjuction' etc are?If it's not, what is it called - a 'function'? If so, what are the names of the other functions, equivalent to 'determiner'? Thanks!

Comment: @BillJ but the term *genitive* is even farther removed from is grammatical function than is the term *possessive.*  The name *genitive* indicates that it is the case of parenthood.

Comment: @stonerocks My apologies, I overlooked your message. When we analyse (parse) clauses, all the words and phrases are assigned two labels: a **functional** label and a **category** one. Functions are subject, object, complement, determiner etc., and categories are noun, verb, adjective, adverb, determinative etc. So determiner is not a category (word class) but a function. That explains why in the NP 'her office', the pronoun 'her' carries the category label "noun" (pronouns are a sub-class of noun) and also the functional label "determiner".

Comment: @phoog "Genitive" is an inflectional case of the noun whose primary use is to mark an NP as determiner within the structure of a larger NP.

Comment: @BillJ the name *genitive* comes from a word meaning "to beget," as do *genus, generate,* and *genital.*  So I do not understand how you can accept that *genitive* is an appropriate name for the grammatical case while rejecting the use of *possessive* for the same case.

Comment: @phoog I've already explained that.- see my last message. And why are you making such a fuss about this old thread? Genitive is the correct term. Deal with it.

Comment: @BillJ possessive is the more widely accepted term and is also correct. I was merely offering another line of thinking to debunk your argument that it somehow isn't. I'm not sure why this thread turned up in the active questions page, but it did. I'm also unsure as to why posting a comment is "such a fuss" -- the only reason I didn't post the comment in August is that I didn't see the question then.

Answer (score -1):

> Both terms are fine; neither is incorrect, and in English they refer to the same phenomena. Genitive has a checkered past as a case name, but English no longer has cases, so possessive carries fewer Latinate presuppositions. The doctor is clearly a noun phrase, and the clitic -'s marks it as a possessive. – John Lawler

Comment: The -'s does not mark it as possessive. The semantic relation between the genitive NP and the following head is by no means limited to that of possession, for example NPs like "her rapid action", "his anger" and so on, have nothing to do with possession. Which is why "genitive" is a better term. "Genitive" is an inflectional **case** of the noun whose primary use to mark an NP as determiner within the structure of a larger NP.